# Web scraping tables with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a code to print on excel a table from an online website. My issue is that I have to apply the code multiple times and I am not sure how to set the Row to start from the first cell that is not filled in. I will not include the code that navigates to the correct page as it is not needed.

```
Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Set HTMLTables = HTMLPage.getElementsByClassName("table")

Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Integer


For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables

                RowNum = 1

        For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                    ColNum = 1

                For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
                      Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = HTMLCell.innerText
                           ColNum = ColNum + 1
                    Next HTMLCell
                        RowNum = RowNum + 1
            Next HTMLRow
      Next HTMLTable
```

My issue is that when the table is printed onto the sheet, if I apply the same code it overwrites what was already written on it and puts the new information into the cells. I would like to basically save one table, then apply this sub again and it will print below the first one on the same worksheet. Overall I want to apply this sub around 100 times and have all of the information onto one worksheet.
I know the issues is that I have set RowNum as Long and = 1 and same for ColNum (row number and column number). I just need to set them up not as numbers but as starting from last available row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the next available row in Column A of the active sheet, try...

```
Dim NextRow As Long

NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

***Edit***

@QHarr is quite right.  In case of empty cells in the column, the following can be used instead...

```
Dim NextRow As Long

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    NextRow = .Rows.Count + .Rows(1).Row
End With
```

Comment: oh thanks for the additional information :), Will also include it in my working. Thanks again

Comment: @QHarr I may be missing something, but it seems to me that UsedRange returns the last row, even with empty rows.  Can you elaborate or provide a link which shows what you mean?

Comment: I am wrong. Remembered incorrectly. Thanks for checking! Here is a better link than my prior   https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Comment: @QHarr Yeah, very true.